# How to find more than one matching sub element

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my nodejs application, I want to find items matching labels.

I have an object with labels:

```
{
    "name": "object1",
    "labels": [
        {"name": "label1"},
        {"name": "label2"}
    }
}
```

From this collection, I want to find all items matching the labels the user provides. `(/api/findLabels/label1,label2)`

At this point, I know I can find this in MongoDB with this query:

```
db.getCollection('items')
    .find(
        {'labels': {
            $elemMatch: 
                {'name': 'label1', 'name': 'label2'}
        }}
```

However, I seem to be having issues with building the query in Node.js.

At this point, I have:

```
Item.find(
    {
        'labels':
        {
            $elemMatch: labels
        }
    }).exec(function(err, items){
        ...
    })
```

But how can I build the correct structure for the labels parameter?
Setting a key more than once with a new value is just replacing the value, not adding it to the list, which makes sense.

Any ideas?

Comment: @neil-lunn Can you verify if my question is still a duplicate with the added info? I have no issues with building the correct MongoDB query, I have issues with building it in my Node.JS app...

Comment: Of course I can verify. Multiple answers there showing use of `.aggregate()` and the `$filter` operator. That is how you return "multiple" matched items from an array.

Comment: Why don't you use normal query using *find()*, I don't think you need `$elemMatch`.

something like this might work: `{ "labels.name": { $in: ["label1","label2"] } }`